# bus error:10 on grunt contrib-watch when updating scss files

Tags: node.js, gruntjs, livereload, grunt-contrib-watch

grunt watch runs and successfully updates js updates, but not scss. I have to wait about a minute for the changes to get picked up. I am running node v0.10.18

> Running "watch" task
> Waiting...OK
>
> > File "app/styles/styles.scss" changed.
>
> Bus error: 10`

Comment: I would suggest posting your issue [here](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-watch/issues) and/or supplying more information about the app structure, OS, environment, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Upgrade your version of node.js `>= 0.10.21`. There is a node bug on the watch within previous versions. See: https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-watch/issues/204